# Create a column based on a multiple conditions in data.table in r

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, min

I am looking to create a new column based on two other column conditions using data.table. Here is my example code:

```
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)  
date <- c(6,2,3,7,6,9,7,1,4,6,8,9)
val1<- c("","A","A","","A","A","","A","A","","A","A")

df1<-data.frame(group,date,val1)
dt1<-as.data.table(df1)
```

Here is the output:

```
 group date val1
 1    6     
 1    2    A
 1    3    A
 2    7     
 2    6    A
 2    9    A
 3    7     
 3    1    A
 3    4    A
 4    6     
 4    8    A
 4    9    A
```

I am looking to find the minimum value of date given that val1 = A within each group (1,2,3,4) to look like this:

```
group date val1 findmin
 1    6             
 1    2    A       Y
 1    3    A        
 2    7             
 2    6    A       Y
 2    9    A        
 3    7             
 3    1    A       Y
 3    4    A        
 4    6             
 4    8    A       Y
 4    9    A
```

I have tried

```
dt1[,findmin:= ifelse(date=min(date[val1 == "A"])),"Y","", by = group]
```

Read as: if date minimum date where val1 = "A", put a "Y" in a new column called 'findmin', else put nothing, and do this for each group (1,2,3,4). I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, , `:=`(findmin, ifelse(min(date[val1 == "A"]))),  : 
  Provide either by= or keyby= but not both
```

I appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Your brackets aren't being closed properly for `ifelse`. The `"Y"` and `""` parts need to be inside the `ifelse(...)` function. You are also using `=` instead of `==` for the comparison part. Try `dt1[,findmin:= ifelse(date==min(date[val1 == "A"]),"Y",""), by = group]`

Comment: you might want to read `?data.table::fifelse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful with your brackets and that equality is checked with `==`:

```
dt1[,findmin := fifelse(date == min(date[val1 == "A"]), "Y", ""), by = group]
```

Comment: This worked. Should I be using "fifelse" with data.table over "ifelse"? @thelatemail who commented earlier didn't use "fifelse" and the code worked just the same

Comment: `data.table::fifelse()` is generally faster and more robust than `base::ifelse()` and therefore preferred when  you use data.table. You can find multiple benchmark comparisons on the web.

Answer (score 1):

This code works using dplyr.  I'm sure there is a much more elegant way to do this.

```
if (!require(dplyr)) {
  install.packages("dplyr")
}
library(dplyr)
if (!require(data.table)) {
  install.packages("data.table")
}
library(data.table)

group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)  
date <- c(6,2,3,7,6,9,7,1,4,6,8,9)
val1<- c("","A","A","","A","A","","A","A","","A","A")

df1<-data.frame(group,date,val1)
dt1<-as.data.table(df1)

# filter for A
df2 <- df1 %>% filter(val1 == "A")

# group by group, arrange by date, get the 1st row, ungroup, add findmin = Y
df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(group) %>% arrange(date) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(findmin = "Y", )

# join back to the original data
df4 <- df1 %>% left_join(df3, by = c("group", "date", "val1"))

# set NA in findmin to "" if you want
df5 <- df4 %>% mutate(findmin = ifelse(is.na(findmin), "", findmin))

# print
df5

   group date val1 findmin
1      1    6             
2      1    2    A       Y
3      1    3    A        
4      2    7             
5      2    6    A       Y
6      2    9    A        
7      3    7             
8      3    1    A       Y
9      3    4    A        
10     4    6             
11     4    8    A       Y
12     4    9    A
```

Testing with randomized data

```
# test randomized
df6 <- sample_frac(df1, size=1)
df6

   group date val1
1      3    4    A
2      3    1    A
3      4    8    A
4      4    6     
5      4    9    A
6      2    9    A
7      2    7     
8      3    7     
9      1    3    A
10     1    6     
11     2    6    A
12     1    2    A

df6 <- df6 %>% 
  filter(val1 == "A") %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(findmin = "Y", )
df7 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df6, by = c("group", "date", "val1")) %>%
  mutate(findmin = ifelse(is.na(findmin), "", findmin)) %>%
  arrange(group, val1, date, findmin)

df7

   group date val1 findmin
1      1    6             
2      1    2    A       Y
3      1    3    A        
4      2    7             
5      2    6    A       Y
6      2    9    A        
7      3    7             
8      3    1    A       Y
9      3    4    A        
10     4    6             
11     4    8    A       Y
12     4    9    A
```

Alternative use which.min in place of arrange and slice

```
df6 <- sample_frac(df1, size=1)
df6
df6 <- df6 %>% 
  filter(val1 == "A") %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(which.min(date)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(findmin = "Y", )
df7 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df6, by = c("group", "date", "val1")) %>%
  mutate(findmin = ifelse(is.na(findmin), "", findmin)) %>%
  arrange(group, val1, date, findmin)

df7

   group date val1 findmin
1      1    6             
2      1    2    A       Y
3      1    3    A        
4      2    7             
5      2    6    A       Y
6      2    9    A        
7      3    7             
8      3    1    A       Y
9      3    4    A        
10     4    6             
11     4    8    A       Y
12     4    9    A
```

Comment: props that you wanted to translate the data.table solution to dplyr. Since I am more a defendant of the tidyverse, I really hope there is a much more elegant solution for this problem..